# Unique names are not coming in jqgrid filter functionality

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jqgrid

I have implemented the filter functionality in jqgrid. The logic is like to iterate on the data of the grid and then find the unique values for the filter. By selecting the values present in the filter we can apply the filter. But One of the strings that is present in the column is coming twice and they are exactly same. For e.g. row 1 : "ABC", row 2: "ABC",row 3: "DEF", row 4: "DEF", row 5 :"FEG" The values in the filter should be ALL,ABC,DEF,FEG but i am getting ALL,ABC,ABC,DEF,FEG. DEF is not repeating. So is it the problem with the string or something else. The code is

```
getUniqueNames = function(columnName) {
        var data = $("#grid0").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');


        var uniqueTexts = [], text, textsMap = {}, i;

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            text=data[i][columnName];


                         if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
                             // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
                             textsMap[text] = true;
                             if (typeof text =="string" && text.trim()!=''){
                             uniqueTexts.push(text);
                             }
                         }
                     }

                 // Object.keys(textsMap); Does not work with IE8: 
                     return uniqueTexts;

    }
```

Comment: Did I got that right? Now chosing "DEF" selects both "DEF" rows but you want the filter to bring both DEF values, in order to be able to select a specific "DEF" row?

Comment: ABC is coming twice in the filter. So when I select one ABC only one row is showing and when i select other ABC then it is showing other row. What I want is ABC is present in both rows, so it should appear only once in the filter and when selected it should select both the rows.